# how to remove space between key-value in SqlConfiguration.ini file using int4j api.

Tags: java, ini4j

**Current Output:**

[SqlServer2008]

INSTALLSHAREDDIR = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
**In Current code, we get space between key-value pair but i do not want.**

**Required Output:**

INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

```
Java code:

Uesin org.ini4j api..............
String installDoc ="F:\\SQLExpressConfigurationFile_x64.ini";
Wini ini;
File file = new File(installDoc);
    try {
    ini = new Wini(file);
ini.put("SQLSERVER2008", "INSTALLSHAREDDIR", "C:\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server");
ini.store();
```

Please let me know how to get required output with ini4j api. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

// difference between  "key = val" or "key=val"

```
ini.getConfig().setStrictOperator(true);
```